# jQuery apply selected value from from one form to another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass the selected value in a multi list form from onto a HubSpot Form using jQuery. The form that I have built looks like the following:

Region, not being passed but first part of the multi list form.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="region">Global Region</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="region" id="region">
    <option value="">Please choose a region</option>
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="Carribean">Carribean</option>
    <option value="Central America">Central America</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
    <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
    <option value="South America">South America</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Country, needs to be passed. Including just the North America section here:

```
<div class="form-group country-north-america hidden">
 <label for="country-north-america">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country-north-america">
        <option value="">Please select a country</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="PM">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands (non-U.S.)">Virgin Islands (non-U.S.)</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Then states for US is another level.

So I've been trying to pass the value from the country to HubSpot form to decrease input repetition. I've updated all the values to actually match HubSpot's value. Thus United States option value is US to match HubSpot's option value.

I have the following that doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out what needs to happen:

```
var country = $('select[name="country"] option:selected').val()
$(window).load(function(){
 $('select[name="country"]').val(country).change();
});
```

I've also tried using the onFormReady from HubSpot to similar results.

```
hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "123",
    formId: "321-123",
    onFormReady($form){
       $('select[name="country"]', $form).val($(country).change());
       $('select[name="state"]', $form).val(state).change(); 
       $('input[name="email"]', $form).val('test@foobar.com').change();
    });
```

How do I pass the country from one form to another with jQuery?

Edit:
I've also tried doing:

```
var country = $('select#country-africa option:checked').val() - Nothing
var country = $('select#country-africa').val('') - I get jQuery.fn.init [select#country-africa.form-control, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "select#country-africa"]
```

Additional Edit:

If I use the following variable I get a full list of countries associated with the region being logged but not applying a change.

```
var country = $('select#country-africa').text()
```

Tried the following:

```
 var country = $('select#country-africa option:checked').val() 
 $(document).ready(function(){ $('select[name="country"]').val(country).trigger('change'); })
```

Didn't work.
Tried the following in my onFormReady:

```
$('select[name="country"]').val('select#country-africa').prop("selected", true).trigger('change');
```

Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.country').on('change', function(e){
    $('select.hs-input[name="country"]').val(e.target.value).trigger('change');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `window.load` event fires the moment the browser window/tab initializes, before the DOM is rendered. So you're not getting the result you want because you're trying to operate on the form before it exists. Try using `document.ready` or just an IIFE passed to the jQuery object instead.

Also, I'm pretty sure the individually named methods for programmatically firing events have been deprecated in favor of `jQuery.trigger()`.

Example code below:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name="country"]')
        .val('whatever')
        .trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Tried the following to no success: var country = $('select#country-africa option:checked').val()
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select[name="country"]').val(country).trigger('change');
       })

Comment: You're still setting the value of the country variable before the DOM is rendered. _Everything_ dealing with elements on the page needs to go within document.ready or IIFE. You can't get the value of a thing that doesn't exist yet.